# Redundant Cloudfront usage?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudfront

I'm curious on my setup regarding usage of cloudfront. Currently I've this setup for my website.

```
Internet_traffic <-> WAF <-> Cloudfront <-> ELB <-> EC2s
```

I've wordpress running on EC2, since there's cloudfront before ELB, does it make any sense to use a separated cloudfront distribution again in the wordpress hosted in the EC2?

Cname for cloudfront before ELB: www.example.com
Cname for cloudfront used in EC2: cdn.example.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use a alternate CF distribution for static assets if the entire site is already behind a cacheing CF configuration.

However, reasons you might want to do that:

- Allow for a different CDN for static assets (ie Fastly / Akamai etc)
- Use a 'cookieless' domain for static assets for greater efficiency

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I can now see the benefit/purpose of using another CF in the EC2, http request sent without original cookies, better user exp